# Cannot import rmagic in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm using jupyer notebook and trying to run R code.

I have installed rpy2 with pip3 (and pip just in case) inside the notebook. What I get when trying to load the extension is this:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
Cannot import 
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I'm using macOS 10.13.4

Thanks

Comment: How you installed jupyter notebook ? using anaconda or pip ?

Comment: using pip @kvmahesh